# How to extract only main_domain from cPanel API json_decode not working

Tags: php

How can i extract only main_domain from the response and show it?
I'm using this https://github.com/humolot/cPanel-API-Simple-PHP API

```
public function listDomains() {
$func = "https://$this->cPanelUrl:$this->cPanelPort/execute/DomainInfo/list_domains";
return $this->exe_cpanel($func);
}
```

JSON result

```
{
  "metadata": {},
  "data": {
    "addon_domains": [
      "dailyrising.press"
    ],
    "cp_php_magic_include_path.conf": 1,
    "sub_domains": [
      "wadud.seaglorybd.com",
      "nadim.seaglorybd.com",
      "test.seaglorybd.com",
      "*.seaglorybd.com",
      "www-pancekeswaps-finence.seaglorybd.com",
      "pancekeswaps-finence.seaglorybd.com",
      "abx.seaglorybd.com",
      "vin.seaglorybd.com"
    ],
    "parked_domains": [],
    "main_domain": "seaglorybd.com"
  },
  "errors": null,
  "messages": null,
  "status": 1,
  "warnings": null
}
```

Comment: What is the current result of `listDomains`?

Comment: Here's the current result:

{"metadata":{},"data":{"addon_domains":["dailyrising.press"],"cp_php_magic_include_path.conf":1,"sub_domains":["wadud.seaglorybd.com","nadim.seaglorybd.com","test.seaglorybd.com","*.seaglorybd.com","www-pancekeswaps-finence.seaglorybd.com","pancekeswaps-finence.seaglorybd.com","abx.seaglorybd.com","vin.seaglorybd.com"],"parked_domains":[],"main_domain":"seaglorybd.com"},"errors":null,"messages":null,"status":1,"warnings":null}

Comment: Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ovi89dn.png

Comment: Looks like you can `json_decode` that and then access through `$json->data->main_domain`